# DatePickerDialog - context parameter in constructor is not accepting

Tags: android

I am trying to make a generic method using Android DatePickerDialog , so instead of using DatePickerDialog  everytime it will be called through a generic function and return the date. It may be part of customized component component as well (i.e. LinearLayout or NavigationView ).

However I am stuck due to context parameter in the constructor of DatePickerDialog . It insist actual activity class name , and I am something looking like parameter ie getContext(), getApplicationContext() etc..

Working but can't be used in generic method - `DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(RecordActivity3.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

Not working - `DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

Not working - `DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

Not working - `DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activityClassParamter, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

Please suggest in case you have worked on similar problem..

Comment: The last one will work if you've declared `activityClassParamter` as an `Activity`, and not just a generic `Context` -- `Activity activityClassParamter`. The `Context` for a `Dialog` has to be an `Activity`.

Comment: where you want to make function ?in the same activity or somewhere?

Comment: @MikeM. - yes It did work, thanks.. I am not able to accept this answer (tick is not showing up ). Can you please respond again in separate thread.. so I can accept it.

Comment: Ah, good. Actually, you can just accept @mallaudin's answer, if you like. They've got the same info. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `activity context` for dialog. Dialog will not work with `application context`. You can read more about context [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

Declare `activity parameter` in your generic dialog function and use it as context.

```
... genericDialog(Activity activity) {
   ... new DatePickerDialog(activity /* note activity context here*/ , ....);
}
```

If you are calling this from an activity, you can just call it like

```
 genericDialog(ActivityClassName.this /* reference to activity */)
```